# Read a DOC file and store text in arraylist android

Tags: android, doc

I have a doc file in which multiple paragraphs are there some headings also. I want headings, paragraphs in an ArrayList of my code. I unable to find my solution regarding the same. Please suggest and suitable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the  code to read the doc file and get the text.
after reading its all depends on you what you want to do with the text.

```
String extPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.Separator;
    AssetManager assetManager= getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(extPath + "file.doc");
    String text = loadFile(inputStream);
```

The loadFile method is---

```
 public String loadFile(InputStream inputStream){
     ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    int length = 0;
      while(){
         b.write(bytes, 0, length);
      }
    return new String(b.toByteArray(), "UTF8");
    }
```